# How do I check if grammar is SLR(1)?

Tags: parsing, grammar, conflict, context-free-grammar, lr-grammar

How do I check if this grammar is SLR(1)?

```
    S' -> S
    S -> [ B
    A -> int
    A -> [ B
    B -> ]
    B -> C
    C -> A ]
    C -> A , C
```

First I've created it's automaton, then computed the follow sets for non-terminals and then created the parsing table.
I'm not sure if my automaton is correct, but after doing the parsing table for SLR(1) grammar I did not find any errors.
Below is my attempt at the automaton.

```
I0:
S' -> .S
S -> .[B

I1 (I0 -> S):
S -> [.B
B -> .]
B -> .C
C -> .A]
C -> .A,C
A -> .int
A -> .[B

I3 (I2 -> B)
S -> [B.

I4 (I2 -> ])
B -> ].

I5 (I2 -> C)
B -> C.

I6 (I2 -> A)
C -> A.]
C -> A.,C

I7 (I2 -> int)
A -> int.

I8 (I2 -> [)
A -> [.B
B -> .]
B -> .C
C -> .A]
C -> .A,C
A -> .int
A -> .[B

I8 -> ] = I4
I8 -> C = I5
I8 -> A = I6
I8 -> int = I7
I8 -> [ = I8 

I9 (I6 -> ])
C -> A].

I10 (I6 -> ,)
C -> A,.C
C -> .A]
C -> .A,C
A -> .int
A -> .[B

I11 (I8 -> B)
A -> [B.

I12 (I10 -> C)
C -> A,C.

I10 -> A = I6
I10 -> int = I7
I10 -> [ = I8
```

Comment: If you can construct a parsing table and there are no conflicts, it's SLR(1). (It certainly looks like it should be; if you left-factor C, then it's LL(1).)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have done the hard work, to find all the states, now it is time to check the Rules of SLR(1).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLR_grammar

As you can realize, your question misses the *Follow()* set which is mandatory in the Rules.

Yes, you can find out on your table parser if there is a conflict or not, but this is an answer depended more on experience than actual science.
Check the Rules one-by-one and you will be fine :)

Depending on the fact that you are sure about the correctness of your states, I see no Shift/Reduce or Reduce/Reduce conflict, so the Grammar is SLR(1)